# scrape the data from html page php

Tags: php, html

I need to scrape the data from an html page

```
<div style="margin-top: 0px; padding-right: 5px;" class="lftFlt1">

    <a href="" onclick="setList1(157204);return false;" class="contentSubHead" title="USA USA">USA USA</a>
    <div style="display: inline; margin-right: 10px;"><a href="" onclick="rate('157204');return false;"><img src="http://icdn.raaga.com/3_s.gif" title="RATING: 3.29" style="position: relative; left: 5px;" height="10" width="60" border="0"></a></div>
    </div>
```

I need to scrape the **"USA USA"** and **157204** from the `onclick="setList1`...

Comment: Do you want to scrap or to scrape? Keep the data or keep the HTML and throw the data away?

Comment: @relet: good question. I see this misspelling often, so I've edited to 'scrape'. @Ram: please rollback if 'scrap' is truly your intent.

Comment: ya thats my mistake i am sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrape web page contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584826/scrape-web-page-contents)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php). RegEx is generally not recommended for parsing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
/setList1\(([0-9]+)\)[^>]+title="([^"]+)"/si
```

and preg_match() or preg_match_all()

Comment: Regex is not the way to parse HTML. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 and other responses on that thread.

Answer (score 1):

Please go [through my previous answers about how to handle HTML with DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+dom).

XPath to get the Text Content of all anchor elements:

```
//a/text()
```

XPath to get the title attribute of all anchor elements:

```
//a/@title
```

XPath to get the onclick attribute of all anchor elements:

```
//a/@onclick
```

You will have to use some string function to extract the number from the onclick text.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best lib for scraping is simple html dom. basically uses jquery selector syntax.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

The way you'd get the data in this example:

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$dom=str_get_html("page.html");
$text=$dom->find(".lftFlt1 a.contentSubHead",0)->plaintext;
//or 
$text=$dom->find(".lftFlt1 a.contentSubHead",0)->title;
```

Comment: That's your opinion. How many other libs have your tried? Suggested third party alternatives that actually use DOM instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: ya it helped for me but one correction 
i changed the $dom=file_get_html("page.html");
can u please explain the .lftFlt1 a.contentSubHead this thing???

Comment: @Ram it's a CSS Selector, which (contrary to steve's suggestion) is not a jQuery thing but a W3C standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: ya ok.. but i am having more class with lftFlt1 in an webpage i used this code it didnt work
 

$dom=file_get_html("http://www.raaga.com/channels/tamil/moviedetail.asp?mid=T0001923");
foreach($text=$dom->find(".lftFlt1 a.contentSubHead",0) as $a)
{
 echo $a->plaintext;
}

Comment: @Ram obviously. the second argument to `find` returns the nth-child. See the docs http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: $str = <<<HTML

<a href="" onClick="setList1(50992);return false;" class="contentSubHead" title="Kakha Kakha">Kakha Kakha</a>


HTML;
$d = str_get_html($str);
foreach($d->find('a') as $e) 

    echo $e->onClick.'<br>';

this return null value i cannot get the value of on click???

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way

```
$a=$coll->find('div[class=lftFlt1]');
$text=$element->find("a[class=cursor]",0)->onclick;
```