# PHP Simple HTML DOM Scrape External URL

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to build a personal project of mine, however I'm a bit stuck when using the Simple HTML DOM class.

What I'd like to do is scrape a website and retrieve all the content, and it's inner html, that matches a certain class.

My code so far is:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
    //use curl to get html content
    $url = 'http://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance-seo-jobs';

    $html = file_get_html($url);

    //Get all data inside the <div class="item-list">
    foreach($html->find('div[class=item-list]') as $div) {
    //get all div's inside "item-list"
    foreach($div->find('div') as $d) {
    //get the inner HTML
    $data = $d->outertext;
    }
    }
print_r($data)
    echo "END";
    ?>
```

All I get with this is a blank page with "END", nothing else outputted at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrape web page contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584826/scrape-web-page-contents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you may want something like this

```
$url = 'http://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance-seo-jobs';
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach ($html->find('div.item-list div.item') as $div) {
    echo $div . '<br />';
};
```

This will give you something like this (if you add the proper style sheet, it'll be displayed nicely)

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Works as expected. How come it wouldn't work when defining the class like: `div[class=item-list]`?

Comment: You probably needed quotes around item-list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your $data variable is being assigned a different value on each iteration.  Try this instead:

```
$data = "";
foreach($html->find('div[class=item-list]') as $div) {
    //get all divs inside "item-list"
    foreach($div->find('div') as $d) {
         //get the inner HTML
         $data .= $d->outertext;
    }
}
print_r($data)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this still wouldn't work. However, when defining the class like Sheikh's answer, it works perfectly.