# I need help creating a Windows 7 Gadget

Tags: javascript, html, windows, widget, windows-desktop-gadgets

I need to create a Windows 7 Gadget (or Widget) as a mini project. I know how to create a basic HelloWorld gadget (including the xml manifest and the html page), but I do not know how to make a complex one.

My company uses a bug tracking software (say, XYZ). My widget needs to be able to access and display data from XYZ regarding bugs, given a bug ID, or other search criteria.

I currently have the APPGUID and server name for XYZ.

Please help. I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

If your bug tracking software (XYZ) is a web application then you need to use its web service or you need to scrape the site to access the data regarding the bugs. You can simply scrape the site using the Simple HTML DOM.

Example can be seen in [PHP Simple HTML DOM Scrape External URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475027/php-simple-html-dom-scrape-external-url)

To download the library the link is http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

Then you can scrape and display the data as the normal HTML code.

OR you have to use the web service provided by the XYZ application.