# Scrape a website to find a unique identifier

Tags: php

My company hands out badges (an image with a link pretty much) to clients all the time to put on their websites. The problem is, we hand out way to many to verify if all clients have actually put them on their websites. Each badge has a unique identifier. Is there anyway to scrape each website through a foreach loop (which I have setup) and look for the unique identifier on each website?

This is an example of the badge(s) we handout:

```
<a style="background:none;" href="javascript:void(window.open('http://livecompliance.com/_badge/badge?d_enc=1f7482917ce3114aafcde4e1f9b6418b','_newwindow', 'toolbar=no,location=yes,status=yes,directories=yes,menubar=yes,scrolling=no,scrollbars=no,width=550,height=330,resize=no'))"><img src="http://www.livecompliance.com/_badge/LC-CE.png" style="margin-right:50px;"></a><br /><a style="color:#333;font-size:11px;font-family:verdana;" href="https://www.livecompliance.com/">www.LiveCompliance.com</a>
```

Comment: Possibly, but only if the website allows scraping from bots/crawlers.

Comment: Most of them should, and if they don't, it wont be a huge issue. I just need something to cut down on time if possible.

Comment: What does your current code look like? And what does the badge's html look like?

Comment: Why not add an identifier to your image url?  That way you can see if that image was requested or not.

Comment: Do you want an answer only in PHP, or are Java/Python also allowed?

Comment: What is your question? How to get started? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584826/scrape-web-page-contents) e.g. then

Comment: @RocketHazmat's idea is better than scraping websites.

Comment: @barakmanos I develop in PHP.

Comment: if your 'badge' makes a request to your server it will be trivial to track what has been loaded

Comment: Posted an example of the badge above. In the href there is a variable "d_enc," that would be my unique identifier.

Comment: Well, if you're planning to run an independent (local) service to do some web-scraping, then it doesn't have to be in PHP. I'm not really familiar with PHP, but as far as I know it's a client side script. Your question suggests that you need something to run independently on the back-end (as a local process, not as a service). Assuming this is indeed the case, then I would recommend you used Selenium web-driver with Java or Python. If you want, I can write you down a coding example in the answer...

Comment: @barakmanos PHP is a ***server side*** script...

Comment: PHP is server side ;)

Answer (score 0):

At first: You said there are many of them. Though "many" is not really a good point to deal with here, when talking about more than 100 this would really indicate NOT doing it in a for-loop.

You will easily come to execution limits! Better solution: Make a queue in a file or in a database where you delete those which were already checked by your script.

Now to the point: Yes it's possible. Probably the most neat solution would be to use CUrl (http://de3.php.net/curl). I will not go deep into CUrl and show you an alternative solution here (though I recommend working with CUrl)

```
$url = 'http://site-to-check.com';
$fetch_html = file_get_contents($url); //better use CUrl ;)
$regexp = '/WHATEVER_PATTERN_FITS_YOUR_NEEDS/i';

if (preg_match($fetch_html,$regexp)) {
    //YES, this site has it
}
```

is this what you asked for ?

Comment: I vote against using ***regex*** to parse HTML. If looking through the HTML is a route you are wanting to take, I would suggest something like [SimpleDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)...

Comment: Could you elaborate on the advantages of `curl` against `file`/`file_get_contents` or SimpleHTMLDomParser?

Comment: @kingkero: Yes I can. Nothing against SimpleHTMLDomParser. But talking about file_get_contents many hosters do NOT support it (talking about remote uris). Many do, but from experience I can tell that most of them support CUrl - that's the main reason. From technical view I'd say both work good.

Comment: Just tested this and `curl` was way faster (usually 3-5times) than `file` or `file_get_contents` (which SimpleHTMLDomParser uses)

Comment: @War10ck: why? Dont you think working the whole thing with an XML parser will take much longer than a perfect regexp? Plesse reconsider your thoughts and provide some reasons

Comment: @androidavid It wasn't what regex was designed to do. There are too many possibilities/variations of code to leave it to a regular expression. An XML parser would be the correct tool in this case. It may be a little bit slower but it is the proper tool for the job. SimpleDOM has some built in features that for example, can still parse invalid markup correctly. This would typically break a regular expression.